# Python List Index out of range shouldn't be an issue

Tags: python

I am using this code to record a key press every time a key is pressed in windows. To my eyes, the code is perfect; no unnecessary loops or undefined variables it should work great.

However, I keep getting this in the terminal:

```
Everything Imported Successfully
Starting Loop
Beginning Checks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\relogged.pyw", line 15, in <module>
    loop(OldKeyChar=[])
  File "C:\Users\***\relogged.pyw", line 9, in loop
    if OldKeyChar[num] == '1': #check to see if key was pressed
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I missing? It should be working, but instead my code causes an error.

```
import win32api 
print("Everything Imported Successfully")

def loop(OldKeyChar):
    print("Beginning Checks")
    while(True): #always checking
        for num in range(0,127): #iterate through list of ascii codes
            if not win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(num): #if key is not being pressed
                if OldKeyChar[num] == '1': #check to see if key was pressed 
                    OldKeyChar[num] = '0' #make sure not recorded again
            else:
            OldKeyChar[num] = '1' #add pressed key to pressed list

OldKeyChar = ['0' for i in range(0,127)]
print("Starting Loop")
loop(OldKeyChar=[])
```

Comment: you have some weird indentation around the `else`...

Comment: @wim - I have learned to ignore indentation issues given sometimes idiosyncratic behavior of the code editor -- especially with users with rep==1. But good eye.

Comment: Ignoring indentation issues when using python isn't the best idea..

Answer (score 1):

`OldKeyChar` is an empty list, so when you run this, it will enter the `while` loop, then enter the `for` loop, assigning `0` to `num`. If a key is being pressed, it will then try and check `OldKeyChar[0]`, which doesn't exist.

The solution to this in your case is to prefill the list with `0`s. You have tried to do this, but for some reason, are passing an empty list instead. As the numbers are immutable, you can actually construct this prefilled list more easily by simply multiplying a list up:

```
loop(OldKeyChar=[0]*128)
```

Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving `CapWords` for classes, and using `lowercase_with_underscores` for other stuff.

Note that I would argue this isn't a great implementation. Instead, consider using a `set` of values pressed in the particular loop:

```
def loop():
    print("Beginning Checks")
    while(True):
        pressed = {i for i in range(0, 127) if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(i)}
```

Here constructed with a [set comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). This allows you to check if a key was pressed or not (if it is in `pressed`, it was, if not, it was not), and there is no need to reset it, as it will be replaced in the next iteration (if you had to keep the same set as you used a reference to it elsewhere, you could `set.clear()` it each iteration, then do an update).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're passing an empty list to the `loop` function?

```
loop(OldKeyChar=[])
```

Should just be this:

```
loop(OldKeyChar)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
loop(OldKeyChar=[])
```

should be

```
loop(OldKeyChar)
```